# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, multer

Pretendo guardar o arquivo na pasta **uploads** e guradar no banco o nome do arquivo.
O `console.log()` me mostra isso:

`{theBook: undefined,
  cover: undefined}`

*Guarda a imagem na pasta **uploads** mas não arquiva o nome no BD*, vindo como **undefined**.

Porque estou tendo este resultado?:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

---

### Meu arquivo:

**eBook.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.model('users');
const requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('../models');
const eBook = mongoose.model('books');
const multer = require('multer');
const uploadConfig = require('../config/upload');

const upload = multer(uploadConfig);
var eBookUpload = upload.fields([
{ name: 'cover', maxCount: 1 }, 
{ name: 'theBook', maxCount: 1 }
]);

router.post('/add', eBookUpload, async (req, res, next) => {
    var erros = []

    if(!req.body.title || typeof req.body.title == undefined || req.body.title == null){
        erros.push({texto: "Título inválido"})
    }

    if(!req.body.author || typeof req.body.author == undefined || req.body.author == null){
        erros.push({texto: "Autor inválido"})
    }

    if(erros.length > 0){
        res.render("pages/ebooks/create", {erros: erros})
    }else{
        const filename = req.file.filename;
        const newBook = {
            title: req.body.title,
            author: req.body.author,
            genre: req.body.genre,
            publisher: req.body.publisher,
            edition: req.body.edition,
            isbn: req.body.isbn,
            pages: req.body.pages,
            theBook: filename,
            cover: filename,
            type: req.body.type,

        }
        new eBook(newBook).save().then(function(){
            req.flash("success_msg", "eBook adicionado com sucesso!")
            res.redirect("/ebook/galeria")
            console.log(newBook)
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
            req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao salvar o eBook! Tente novamente")
            res.redirect("/ebook/galerias")
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Segundo seu código o esperado para o `console.log` não é `{ theBook: undefined,
  cover: undefined }` visto que você está passando como parâmetro a constante `newBook`. 

Se entendi bem, sua imagem está sendo salva fisicamente mas as informações no `req.body` não estão sendo preenchidas e por isto você não consegue salvar as informações da constante `newBook` no banco de dados?

Comment: Não, é o contrário... Os dados do `req.body` são salvos no banco e o `req.file` não. Apenas guarda fisicamente na pasta **uploads** e não regista o nome do ficheiro no baco dados nos campos **theBook** e **cover**.

Comment: se entendi corretamente o comportamento é este mesmo. O arquivo é salvo fisicamente na pasta **uploads**. No seu banco de dados você deve criar uma referência para este arquivo salvando seu nome, por exemplo. Os bytes da imagem não ficarão salvas no banco de dados a não ser que você altere seu código e adote uma nova estratégia. Você gostaria de salvar a imagem diretamente no banco de dados?

Comment: Veja se este post te ajuda, caso eu não tenha compreendido bem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359137/how-may-i-upload-file-with-formdata-to-node-js-with-express

Comment: É isso mesmo que eu gostaria, mas no entanto ele não guarda o nome do arquivo no banco de dados. Retorna **undefined**. Tens uma ideia de como melhorar isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muitas semanas de pesquisas, finalmente consegui resolver o problema.
A solução é simples `req.files[nome-do-campo][0].filename`... Deste modo a implementação ficaria assim:

```
router.post('/add', accessControl, fileBook, async (req, res, next) => {
var erros = []

    if(!req.body.title || typeof req.body.title == undefined || req.body.title == null){
        erros.push({texto: "Título inválido"})
    }

    if(!req.body.author || typeof req.body.author == undefined || req.body.author == null){
        erros.push({texto: "Autor inválido"})
    }

    if(erros.length > 0){
        res.render("pages/ebooks/create", {erros: erros})
    }else{
        //const { filename } = req.file;
        const newBook = {
            title: req.body.title,
            preface: req.body.preface,
            author: req.body.author,
            genre: req.body.genre,
            publisher: req.body.publisher,
            edition: req.body.edition,
            isbn: req.body.isbn,
            pages: req.body.pages,
            cover: req.files['cover'][0].filename,
            theBook: req.files['theBook'][0].filename,
            type: req.body.type,
            tags: req.body.tags

        }
        new eBook(newBook).save().then(function(){
            req.flash("success_msg", "eBook adicionado com sucesso!");
            res.redirect("/ebook/biblioteca");
            console.log(newBook);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao salvar o eBook! Tente novamente");
            res.redirect("/ebook/biblioteca");
        });
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que vc tem um array de files, então seria:

```
const filename = req.files[index].filename;
```

Comment: O `index` precisa ser definido, do contrario o seu papel não será especifico. continuaremos tendo mesmo problema de **undefined** ou **not defined**.

Answer (score 0):

Horácio, o exemplo abaixo é um código que escrevi há um tempo e que funciona corretamente. Retirei alguns pontos que não fazem parte do entendimento. Outro ponto é que se for trabalhar com Array os arquivos devem ser acessados através do `req.files` ao invés do `req.file`:

```
exports.post = async (req, res) => {
    var multer = null;
    try {
        multer = require('multer');
    } catch (ex) {
        // TODO console.error(ex);
        // TODO return res.json();
    }

    var upload = null;
    try {
        var path = require('path');
        var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                // process.env.DIRETORIOUPLOAD = diretório
                // onde o arquivo será salvo
                cb(null, process.env.DIRETORIOUPLOAD);
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                fileExtension = file.originalname.split('.')[1];

                // Não faz parte da questão mas estou dando um novo nome para o arquivo
                // físico
                const novoNome = require('crypto').randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
                cb(null, novoNome + path.extname(file.originalname));
            }
        });

        upload = multer({ storage: storage }).fields([
            // O name do input deve ser "anexo"
            { name: 'anexo', maxCount: 1 }
        ]);
    } catch (ex) {
        // TODO console.error(ex);
        // TODO return res.json();
    }

    upload(req, res, async err => {
        if (err) {
            // TODO console.error(ex);
            // TODO return res.json();
        }

        var obj = {
            // Informações postadas além do anexo
            campo1: req.body.campo1,
            campo2: req.body.campo2,

            // Novo nome do arquivo atribuído mais acima
            nomeArquivo: req.files['anexo'][0].filename,
            extensao: req.files['anexo'][0].filename.split('.')[1],

            // Nome original do arquivo
            nomeOriginal: req.files['anexo'][0].originalname,
            mimetype: req.files['anexo'][0].mimetype
        };

        // TODO salvar o "obj" no DB
        // TODO res.json();
    });
}
```

Mais detalhes sobre a documentação: https://github.com/expressjs/multer